# Accepted:Answered Ratio Badge

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

How about introducing a badge which will be awarded for a high ratio of accepted answers to total answered. Although this ratio will change time to time, therefore it might not be much good, but there are similar badges like "Unsung Hero" and "Tenacious" . A bronze badge and a silver badge for a certain threshold for the said ratio and a gold badge for a higher threshold, might make the users trying to write answers in a more acceptable way and make more competitive. I think this is not a bad idea.

Comment: I just realized I totally misread your question.  Your proposed badge is for the answerers, and I thought it was for the askers.  Apologies! I've deleted my answer and reversed my downvote, +1.

Comment: Yes, definitely the badge proposed is for the askers because of their hardwork for trying to getting more accepted answers. This badge might reflect an expertise and the accuracy of the user who provides a lot quality answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think overall this badge would encourage positive behavior.

1. New users are less likely to get their questions answered if you do this, because it motivates people to skip questions where the answer is less likely to be accepted, and many first time askers don't know to accept an answer.
2. It will discourage people from posting a relatively late answer that is better than already upvoted answers as it is less likely to get accepted. It will especially discourage people from adding a better answer after an answer is accepted, as the OP is unlikely to switch their accept.
3. Users already get bugged enough (sometimes by me) to accept answers -- this will only make it worse.
4. We already reward accepted answers with Enlightened and Guru if they are first and with 10 score, or with 40 score.

Comment: the point 2 is very good.

Comment: @phoxis I now numbered them :)

Comment: i will accept your answer because of the point 2, it is a strong one.

Comment: Point 1 didn't occur to me.  Fully agreed.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree. It puts too much emphasis on the best answer. The other answers, which are not accepted, might be as good as the best answer.

Comment: the acceptance is totally upon the asker, and there a lot good answers which are unaccepted, but mostly accepted answers are good. I will accept an answer which is better among the others. I partially agree with you, but i do not think there is too much emphasis on the best answer, instead it will be an encouragement for a user to make accurate answers and make it even better.

Comment: Agree with this. Also, there are already two badges for getting accepted answers (Enlightened and Guru). Both can be earned multiple times.